# Overflow in Numpy Cosh Function

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting overflow error at cosh function in this simplified code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
for i in range(np.size(x)):
    print np.cosh(20*x[i]**2)
```

Is there a way to workaround this easily?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that function? The last element in x is `10` , and for that you are trying to take cosh of `2000` , which is infinity.

Comment: @AnandSKumar, that is needed for a complicated simulation. Actually, I am going to calculate 1/np.cosh(...) function thus converging to zero quickly over x. However it cannot calculate the zero due to overflow.

Comment: The best way to handle this will depend on what you're actually trying to do.  It's unlikely that you really need to compute cosh values so large they won't even fit in a float.

Comment: Also, I tried this in Python 2.7 - https://ideone.com/XugQ4F - The Overflow is a warning , are you getting it as an error?

Comment: @AnandSKumar cosh(2000) is on the order of 10^868, which is big, but it certainly is not infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to deal with large numbers, [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/) is useful:

```
import sympy as sy

x = sy.symbols("x", real=True)

y = 1/sy.cosh(x)
print(y.subs(x, 2000).evalf())  # => 5.15307174592230e-869
```

To determine a bound to prevent an overflow, consider that the maximum float value is 1.79769e+308. Hence

```
print(sy.acosh(1.79769e+308).evalf()) # => 710.475858330117
```

So you could do

```
inv_acosh = lambda x: 1/np.cosh(x) if abs(x) < 710.4 else 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

lambda x: 0.5/cosh(np.minimum(np.abs(x), 700.0*np.ones(x.shape)))

Comment: Please provide an entire working answer. The code you have given would not work as written and you have not given any instructions on how to use it.